# Check if Excel is in dirty state

Tags: c#, excel

Is there any way I can know if Excel is in dirty state or not.

By dirty state I mean:-
When you do anything on Excel and close save button - Excel asks you to save the file.
So there must be some flag which is set when the file is edited.

Can I know the status of an Excel file through C# code?

Searched a lot, but not much help is available. One option is there which allows you to know if Excel is in edit state or not by looking at `GetRibbonControlEnabled("FileNewDefault")`

In this case you can see if Excel is in edit state only at the time when you execute this method.

What if I want to know if Excel was edited/made dirty since the time it was open.

Please don't advice to start to background thread which keeps looking if Excel was in edit mode by using the above function.

An help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [`Workbook.Saved`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saved%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. It will tell you if the user has modified the document since it was last opened.

```cs
bool isDirty = !Globals.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved;
```

Comment: Corrected - nice catch @GordThompson!

Answer (score 3):

In an Excel VBA module one can test the `ActiveWorkbook.Saved` property, and if it is `False` then the workbook has unsaved changes (is "dirty"). Details [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213634). See if you can check that property from your C# code.